# javascript slideshow overlay

Tags: javascript, image, gallery, slideshow

i would like to make image slideshow.
First, i would have just thumbnails and when clicked on the one, it would pop up overlay(some sort of div, or something) and there would be option to move through the images. I don't want to use anykind of libraries

i have this, so far:

```
    NewImg = new Array (
"img/1gif",
"img/2gif",
"img/3gif"
);
var ImgNum = 0;
var ImgLength = NewImg.length - 1;
var delay = 3000;
var lock = false;
var run;
function chgImg(direction) {
if (document.images) {
ImgNum = ImgNum + direction;
if (ImgNum > ImgLength) {
ImgNum = 0;
}
if (ImgNum < 0) {
ImgNum = ImgLength;
}
document.slideshow.src = NewImg[ImgNum];
   }
}
function auto() {
if (lock == true) {
lock = false;
window.clearInterval(run);
}
else if (lock == false) {
lock = true;
run = setInterval("chgImg(1)", delay);
   }
```

html part

```
<a href="javascript:chgImg(-1)">Previous</a>
<a href="javascript:auto()">Auto/Stop</a>
<a href="javascript:chgImg(1)">Next</a>
```

this is the regular image gallery. With regular sized images.
I don't know how to implement those thumbnails 
thank for helping me around here

i forgot, i have 
used following code for overlays(but don't know how to implement it here)

```
function toggleLayer( whichLayer )
{
  var elem, vis;
  if( document.getElementById ) 
  {
    elem = document.getElementById( whichLayer );
  }  
  vis = elem.style;
  if(vis.display==''&&elem.offsetWidth!=undefined&&elem.offsetHeight!=undefined)
    vis.display = (elem.offsetWidth!=0&&elem.offsetHeight!=0)?'block':'none';
  vis.display = (vis.display==''||vis.display=='block')?'none':'block';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sevdah/z7Ggx/1/ on jsfiddle, but it is not working, don't know why

Comment: Please post it as a fiddle! Thanks.. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sevdah/z7Ggx/1/